# d3 v3: transition() is breaking changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3.js (v3), I have written a bar chart with the following code, which works fine:

```
var bars = innerChart.selectAll("rect.data-bar")
            .data(data, d => d.label);

        bars.exit()
            .attr("width", 0)
            .attr("y", zeroY)
            .attr("height", 0)
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .remove();

        bars.enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "data-bar")
            .attr("width", 0)
            .attr("y", zeroYPrev)
            .attr("height", 0)
            .style("cursor", "pointer")
            .on("click", d => {
                onBarClick(d);
            });

        bars
            .attr("x", (d, i) => {
                if (i > 0) {
                    var start = 0;
                    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        start += data[j].data[0].x * wRatio;
                    }
                    return start
                } else { return zeroX }
            })
            .attr("y", d => {
                if (d.data[0].y < 0) { return zeroY }
                else { return zeroY - (Math.abs(d.data[0].y) * hRatio) }
            })
            .attr("width", d => (d.data[0].x * wRatio) < .5 ? .5 : (d.data[0].x * wRatio) - .5)
            .attr("height", d => yScale(Math.abs(d.data[0].y) * hRatio))
            .style("fill", d => coloursDict[d.label])
            .style("opacity", 0.5);
```

However, as soon as I add transitions into the code the data change doesn't work at all. To be clear, it's not that the transition doesn't work, it's that the bars in the chart no longer change at all. The `bars.exit()` selection is not removed, the `bars.enter()` selection is not added, and no bars move at all. Here is the code with the transitions added:

```
var bars = innerChart.selectAll("rect.data-bar")
            .data(data, d => d.label);

        bars.exit()
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("width", 0)
            .attr("y", zeroY)
            .attr("height", 0)
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .remove();

        bars.enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "data-bar")
            .attr("width", 0)
            .attr("y", zeroYPrev)
            .attr("height", 0)
            .style("cursor", "pointer")
            .on("click", d => {
                onBarClick(d);
            });

        bars
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("x", (d, i) => {
                if (i > 0) {
                    var start = 0;
                    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        start += data[j].data[0].x * wRatio;
                    }
                    return start
                } else { return zeroX }
            })
            .attr("y", d => {
                if (d.data[0].y < 0) { return zeroY }
                else { return zeroY - (Math.abs(d.data[0].y) * hRatio) }
            })
            .attr("width", d => (d.data[0].x * wRatio) < .5 ? .5 : (d.data[0].x * wRatio) - .5)
            .attr("height", d => yScale(Math.abs(d.data[0].y) * hRatio))
            .style("fill", d => coloursDict[d.label])
            .style("opacity", 0.5);
```

What am I getting wrong here?